# Django testing: DatabaseError: no such table for ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, manytomanyfield

I've written a couple of tests for really simple blog app, but the many to many relationship fails when I run the test: `./manage.py test myblog`

```
DatabaseError: no such table: myblog_post_tag
```

Yet when I do `./manage.py sql myblog`:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "myblog_tag" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "myblog_post_tag" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "post_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "tag_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "myblog_tag" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("post_id", "tag_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "myblog_post" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL,
    "content" text NOT NULL
)
;
COMMIT;
```

It does create a table, yet it fails to do so while testing? Any help is appreciated.
Here's my test:

```
class TagModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_create_tags_for_posts(self):
        # tests tagging posts, postodd will have tags 1 & 3, posteven will be 2 & 4
        postodd = Post(
            title="testing odd tags",
            pub_date=timezone.now(),
            content='''hello everybody, we are testing some tagging
                functionality here. This post should have odd tags.''',
        )
        posteven = Post(
            title="test even tags",
            pub_date=timezone.now(),
            content ='''hello everybody, we are testing some tagging
                functionality here. This post should have even tags.''',
        )
        #save them to db
        postodd.save()
        posteven.save()

        # create the  tags
        tag1 = Tag(name="1")
        tag2 = Tag(name="2")
        tag3 = Tag(name="3")
        tag4 = Tag(name="4")

        # save all tags to db
        tag1.save()
        tag2.save()
        tag3.save()
        tag4.save()

        # create the many2many relationship
        postodd.tag.add(tag1)
```

And my models.py if needed:

```
from django.db import models


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date published")
    content = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1):

`./manage.py sql myblog` does not execute the SQL, it just outputs what it *would* execute if you ran `syncdb`.

In this case, it seems the table is missing from your db.

If this was a result of a modification to an existing app; for example you just added a new field to your model; then running `syncdb` won't affect the changes to your database. `syncdb` doesn't do any destructive operations (like adding or dropping tables or columns).

In this case you can manually run the query to add the column; or drop and recreate your tables with `syncdb`.

Since this is a common problem most people use a data migration tool like [`south`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/index.html) to handle these changes for you. South will manage these small changes intelligently.

Comment: But I'm not using syncdb. Right now I'm only running tests, so when I run a test, doesn't it create a testing database anyway?